# Unreliable Wireless Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I've been using Ubuntu for a while, but a recurring problem I've experienced is that connections to wireless networks, particularly eduroam, are very unstable. As soon as I connect myself to the network, it's only a matter of time, 10 minutes at most, before I immediately disconnect and am prompted for the network's password.

My laptop is an ASUS N56JR with an Intel Dual Band Wireless-N 7260 network adapter. I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I assure you I've tried many of the other question's suggestions, to no avail.

I should also add that I dualboot Ubuntu (14.04) with Windows 8.1, and I have none of the issues I've described here on Windows, which leads me to believe this is has to do with my drivers on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guess...but this may be due to varying signal strength of your connection.

I use the network connections program, which is by default on the xfce panel.  Edit the connection you are trying to use, and enter the MAC address of the hotspot you are connecting to (not your MAC) into the BSSID field. then save.  This causes the software to weld itself to that connection, even though surrounding signals may be stronger. You may need something like WiFi Radar to find out what the MAC address is.

I'm running xfce, so this may vary depending on your gui, and how network connections are handled on your system.  Hope this helps.